# how to view docx file in html page?

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, docx

I have develop one web application using spring MVC, in my application i have to read docx file on web page and it has work offline also. How can i do this , is any jquery plugin available. please give me solution.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be docx?  Could just use XML and pass it into the page :-)

Answer (score 0):

How a downloaded file is opened is all down to the user's local PC settings. You cannot force a document to display in browser.